# Optimizing Gas Costs and Replacing For Loops in Solidity Function with Large Dataset

Tags: gas, solidity-0.8.x, merkle-patricia-tries, optimization

I have a Solidity smart contract with a function drawLottery that processes a large dataset of potentially 1 million tickets. The function contains several for loops for iterating through the tickets and performing various operations, such as checking for winners and resetting values.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
    function setTicketWinner() internal {
        uint8[6] memory winningNumbers = [3, 5, 6, 16, 25, 19];
        for (uint i = 0; i < currentTicketId; i++) {
            Ticket memory ticket = tickets[i];
            wins[ticket.owner] = Matches.NONE;
            price[currentRoundId][ticket.owner] = 0;
            if (
                ticket.coinsForGrandPrize >= 3 && _isGrandPriceWinningTicket(ticket.numbers, winningNumbers)
            ) {
                wins[ticket.owner] = Matches.GRAND_PRICE;
            }
            if (wins[ticket.owner] != Matches.GRAND_PRICE && ticket.coinsForMatchDraw >= 1) {
                uint8 matchCount = _isCountWinningTicket(ticket.numbers, winningNumbers);
                if (matchCount >= 3) {
                    wins[ticket.owner] = Matches.MATCH_DRAW_PRICE;
                }
            }
            if (ticket.coinsForOverUnderDraw >= 1 && wins[ticket.owner] == Matches.NONE) {
                if (_isOverUnderDrawWinningTicket(ticket, winningNumbers[5])) {
                    wins[ticket.owner] = Matches.OVER_UNDER_DRAW_PRICE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm concerned about the efficiency of the code and potential high gas costs when dealing with such a large number of tickets. I would like to optimize the code and replace the for loops with a more gas-efficient approach. How can I achieve this in Solidity? Are there any design patterns or strategies I can use to handle large datasets more efficiently?

Additionally, I want to emphasize that ticket verification must be done on-chain for security and transparency reasons, while other non-security-critical operations can be off-chain to improve efficiency.

I've considered a **Merkle tree** solution, but it's not ideal for my use case because it doesn't allow me to ***retrieve the winning numbers associated with a specific ticket*** or verify which draw that ticket has won.

Any guidance, code examples, or best practices for improving gas efficiency and avoiding for loops in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are handling big datasets like you mentioned, you really should stray away from looping through them as the gas costs would be massive and in some cases irrational.

I know you want it to be as on-chain and transparaent as possible, which may make this solution slightly unattractive to you, but consider this:

1. Supply the lottery contract with the value that will be rewarded to winners at the beginning of the contest
2. Once the contest period has ended: create a Merkle Tree using leaves that contain relevant data such as the winner's address or the winning tickets id, etc. Make the construction process of the tree publicly known so that anyone can verify its authenticity.
3. Make a function call to the lottery contract with the Merkle Tree's root.
4. Now anyone who has a winning ticket can create proof and claim their winnings. (*your `claim` contract would verify the proof and that the owner of the ticket is the caller*).

Handling the reward amount to send can be done in a few ways. One method would be to pass the total number of winners as a variable along with the Merkle Root, then when users claim their portion, you simply send them a fraction of the total prize correlating to the total number of winners. So if the prize of the lottery was 10 ETH and 5 users have winning tickets, each user's reward would be 2 ETH.

Comment: Thanks for the Merkle Tree approach. However, our lottery has different prize levels that depend on the ticket's specific numbers, and the prizes are not evenly split. A Merkle Tree can't show which prize level a ticket has won. Plus, we need to keep the exact ticket numbers private.

We're looking for a way to validate winning tickets and their prize levels on-chain while keeping costs low. Any thoughts on how we could modify your suggestion to handle these requirements?

Comment: @PraveenMatheesha How are you intending to keep the ticket numbers for each user private? Are the tickets bought off-chain and the numbers are only known to the user? I'm confused about how the flow of your project works. Do users input their winning tickets themselves before the winning numbers are posted? If so you could simply post the winning numbers and then have users call a claim function that processes their winnings based on the numbers they have. Users could pay for the lottery ticket to the contract when they upload their numbers on-chain.

Comment: I made my code as you said, Like In the backend we are calculating winners and set to a struct mapping to a roundId, and after that when a user submit their ticket the claim function looking at each root like 

struct MerkleTrees{
  bytes32 grandPriceWinners;
  bytes32 overUnderDrawWinners;
  bytes32 matchDraw5Winners;
  bytes32 matchDraw4Winners;
  bytes32 matchDraw3Winners;
}

And If found the ticket in where ever that struct ticket will be take as a rewarding one to that winning category. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code correctly, its seems that you need to check every single ticket as there is different prizes. So if you have N tickets you would need N iterations anyway, using a for loop or anything else to do it.

One thing you could maybe do is stopping the loop if all winning tickets have been found, if you are able in advance to know the number of winning tickets. This seems to depend on how the tickets number are generated (random, unique, chosen by participants?). Depending on the number of winners and odds, this could save quite a bit of gas.

Otherwise, I can think of two solutions to avoid using a costly loop:

1. Create a function that only generate and publish the winning numbers, and let the users themselves claim their reward if any. Downside is that it won't be done automatically in a single call.
2. Compute the winning numbers, then call a `view` function (which does not cost gas when called outside of a smart contract) that returns all winning numbers participant and their rewards. Then call the function setting the rewards for these participant using the previous function data. Downside may be that you could temper with the winning numbers, leading to distrust from participant.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but my main concern is with the lottery's reward system, which is proportional to the total pot. Since the winner's share depends on the total number of winning tickets, and winners claim at varying times, we can't pre-calculate each winner's share. The challenge is creating a fair, transparent on-chain system that allows for dynamic reward determination as winners come forward to claim their prizes. How can we manage this without knowing the final number of winners in advance?